# Showing Recent file

Tags: asp.net-2.0

I am having one folder which contain all excel files.I want to show programmatically recent excel file in the page to download.I am using C#.net.plz help.

Answer (score 1):

If by *recent* you mean recently written to then you could use the following code to gather all excel files in a given directory and order them by last write time:

```
var files = from f in new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\some_directory").GetFiles("*.xls")
            orderby f.LastWriteTime descending
            select f;

foreach (var file in files)
{
    Console.WriteLine(file);
}
```

Other properties of [FileInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.aspx) that might interest you are [LastAccessTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.lastaccesstime.aspx) and [CreationTime](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filesysteminfo.creationtime.aspx).

---

EDIT: Sorry I didn't notice you were using .NET 2.0. So here is the equivalent code for finding all excel files in a given directory and order them by last write time:

```
List<FileInfo> files = new List<FileInfo>(new DirectoryInfo(@"c:\some_directory")
    .GetFiles("*.xls"));
files.Sort(delegate(FileInfo f1, FileInfo f2) 
{ 
    return f2.LastWriteTime.CompareTo(f1.LastWriteTime); 
});
```

In your question you mention downloading files in ASP.NET application. So once you have retrieved the list of files you can show it to the user in a table so that he can pick up the desired file to download.

Comment: code is not clear... were i have to mention this "orderby f.LastWriteTime descending" plz help